# static files not loaded with Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

Hi I'm learning Django through Onemonth Python and got an error loading static files. The output html points to the right location of the file. I use Django 1.82 on OSX Yosemite. Could someone help?

Here is my files. 
settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MAIN_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'nomadscoffee.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'nomadscoffee.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(MAIN_DIR,'templates'),
#     )

STATIC_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(MAIN_DIR,'static'),
    )
```

Index.html (some parts)

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Agency - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{% static "css/agency.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="{% static "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top" class="index">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro-text">
                <div class="intro-lead-in">Welcome To Our Studio!</div>
                <div class="intro-heading">It's Nice To Meet You</div>
                <a href="#services" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Tell Me More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Services Section -->
    <section id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Services</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                </div>
```

Comment: Do you get an error (if so, what is it?), or the static file does not load?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I have no problem loading the index.html but all local static files don't load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `STATICFILES_DIRS` instead of `STATIC_DIRS` in your `setting.py` file.